# how to reference a class which is extending a class and implementing an interface

Tags: java, interface

I have a class which is extending another class and implementing one interface , so now what will be the reference type of the class.As now I getting `ClasscastException` if I am trying to convert the base type into child type.

For example

```
public class Child extends Parent implements SomeInterface
{

}

SomeInterface childObject = new Child();
childObject2 = (Child)childObject;
```

or

```
Parent p = new Child();
childObject2 = (Child)p;
```

in both cases I am getting `class cast exception`

Comment: can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: I didn't see any error in above code. Every thing valid u have done.Post your full stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

You can not cast the object of subclass to superclass.As superclass has generalized characteristics while subclass has special characteristics.

```
   SuperClass sup = (SuperClass) new SubClass();
   SubClass sub1 = (SubClass) sup;
```

You can refere : [Casting super class to sub class](http://www.coderanch.com/t/416816/java/java/Casting-super-class-class)